# fallo en la ejecucion

Tags: python

hola tengo un problema con un programa que meda el resultado promedio de notas de alumnos el siclo while sigue y no se frena me sigue pidiendo materia y nota no sale del bucle aqui le expongo como lotengo echo aversialguien me puede ayudar gracias

```
# Solicitar información

nombre= input("Ingreses el nombre completo: ")
materias =5

#Hacer un ciclo y pedir datos y sumar la calificacion

contador = 1
sumatoria = 0

while contador <= materias:

    nombre_materia = input("Ingresa el nombre de la (" +str(contador) + ") materia: ")

    calificacion = float(input('Calificación obtenidas en: ' +str(nombre_materias) + ": "))

# Sumar la calificación a la sumatoria

sumatoria = sumatoria + calificacion

#Aumentar el contador para no hacer un ciclo infinito

contador = contador + 1

#Hacer caldulos e imprimir resutados

promedio = sumatoria / materias

print("***RESULTADO***")
print(f'Hola, {nombre} tienes un promedio de {promedio} en el 5to semestre.')
```

Comment: El código está mal indentando. El `while` sólo incluye dos instrucciones, y el contador nunca se incrementa. Solución: indentar correctamente

Answer (score 0):

el problema con tu código es que en el bucle `while` no estas incrementado el valor del contador, por lo tanto nunca se cumple la condición del contador, es decir, el contador nunca es mayor que el número de materias.

Para solucionar esto lo único que tienes que hacer es mover el incremento del contado dentro del bucle, ya que si lo pones fuera el programa se quedará ejecutando el bucle infinitamente ya que no llega a la condición de incrementar el contador.

El código con el contador corregido:

```
# Solicitar información

nombre= input("Ingreses el nombre completo: ")
materias =5

#Hacer un ciclo y pedir datos y sumar la calificacion

contador = 1
sumatoria = 0

while contador <= materias:

    nombre_materia = input("Ingresa el nombre de la (" +str(contador) + ") materia: ")

    calificacion = float(input('Calificación obtenidas en: ' +str(nombre_materias) + ": "))
#Aumnetar el contador para  no hacer un bucle infinito
    contador += 1 

# Sumar la calificación a la sumatoria

sumatoria = sumatoria + calificacion


#Hacer caldulos e imprimir resutados

promedio = sumatoria / materias

print("***RESULTADO***")
print(f'Hola, {nombre} tienes un promedio de {promedio} en el 5to semestre.')
```